# javascript: Can get the width and height of original picture?

Tags: javascript, image, image-uploading

I have a user-uploaded image, which is displayed as a small icon however I need to determine the original picture height and width. How can I get them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.naturalWidth/.naturalHeight`, though it will not work in older IE.

http://jsfiddle.net/kBRtX/

Answer (score 2):

Use the object attribute width and height for that. Look at the following example:

```
var imgObj = new Image()
    imgObj.src = "http://www.muenzenpara.de/muenzenmotive/griechenland_euro.jpg";
    alert(imgObj.width);
    alert(imgObj.height);
```